# What chests count for "Chestmaster 2000"?

Tags: diablo-iii, achievements

I opened a regular chest (called "Chest") and my "Chestmaster 2000" score did not increase. Does it only count "Resplendent Chests" or what?

[image: Chestmaster 2000]

Answer (score 4):

Chests and all variations (Bloody, Resplendent, and so on) count.  It does not appear that containers count, such as corpses, crates, egg sacks, or demon vessels.  That is what it I got from testing so far, but have not looked at it in depth.

Note the achievements do not always update instantaneously.

Answer (score 0):

While all variations of the basic "chest" do count, the clouds and other lootable objects (pots of gold, etc) in Whimsyshire (which function exactly as normal chests, besides the model) do **not** count.