# Do the "happy clouds" in Whimsyshire count as chest for Chestmaster 2000?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What chests count for “Chestmaster 2000”?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/69016/what-chests-count-for-chestmaster-2000)

In Whimsyshire there seem to be a pretty good quantity of "Happy clouds" that drop loot when you "open" them.  Are these chests?  Do they count towards the "Chestmaster 2000" achievement?